# Is my programming logic correct here?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, optimization

```
const char IsPressed = 1; // 1
const char WasHeldDown = 2; // 10
const char IsFirstPress = 4; // 100

char* keystates[256];

Class::CalculateKeyStates()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        if(this->IsDown(i))
        {
            keystates[i] |= IsPressed; // turn on
            if(keystates[i] & WasHeldDown)
            {
                //keystates[i] |= IsFirstPress;
                keystates[i] &= ~IsFirstPress; // turn off
            }
            else
            {
                keystates[i] |= WasHeldDown + IsFirstPress; // Turn on
            }
        }
        else
        {
            keystates[i] = 0; // Turn ALL off
        }
    }
}
```

This function would be a member function of a class, Class. The other member function, IsDown, will return a true if the key in question is down and false if not.

Can you see any way of further improving this function?

Thanks

EDIT:

I will expand a bit as to what is done why. This is a modification of an bit of code that works through an array keyStates (which was a struct of three bools) setting IsPressed to false for all of the keys. then again setting Ispressed to the value of this->IsDown and then a third time looping through checking if the key had been held, if it has then its no longer the first press so set that to false. if it was not held down, then set first press to true and was held to true as well, so next time it is flagged as having been held.

EDIT2:

Added some comments to code and corrected one line

Comment: Add comments? About what you are trying to do and why you are doing it that way, and what are the inputs and the outputs of your function.

Comment: A bit off topic, but many keyboard API are event based, in which case you can just listen for key events and update the model in those events.

Comment: @mouviciel, whilst I would not say that comments are not needed at all. This code is fairly self explanatory is it not? clearly, there is no I/O. I would accept that the bitwise could do with commenting, except a programmer probably should be able to know what a bitwise operation is doing.

Comment: @thecoshman, I see at least one input: `this->IsDown(i)`. I can infer that `this` represents a keyboard containing 256 keys and `i` is a key ID and `IsDown(i)` returns `TRUE` if key #i is down. But I would like to know more on the dynamics of the program: when is this code called? every x seconds? after an interrupt related to keyboard action? What does `IsDown(i)` actually return? the current state of the key? the last sampled state of the keyboard?

Comment: but this->IsDown(i) is just being used by this function. If IsDown need commenting, to explain what the parameter does and what IsDown returns, then such commenting would be with the code implements IsDown, not ever where that IsDown gets called. As for when this function is getting called, again that is out side of the scope of this function, it needs not know every where it is getting called, just that it should do what it needs to do when it is called. This the point libraries of code, you don't question how they do what they do, you just make expect them to do what they say they will

Comment: Without knowing the dynamics, I am not able to make the link between isDown and IsPressed, IsFirstPress, WasHeldDown. What if the key state changes twice between two calls? Your programming logic is correct under certain assumptions but I know nothing about these assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would define the key-states as disjoint states and write a simple state-machine, thus:

```
enum keystate
{
    inactive,
    firstPress,
    active
};

keystate keystates[256];

Class::CalculateKeyStates()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        keystate &k = keystates[i];

        switch (k)
        {
        inactive:
            k = (isDown(i)) ? firstPress : inactive;
            break;
        firstPress:
            k = (isDown(i)) ? active : inactive;
            break;
        active:
            k = (isDown(i)) ? active : inactive;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is easier to extend, and easier to read if it gets any more complex.

Comment: I really should stop forgetting about enums being in C++ and not just c#. I do like this solution, does make help if you consider the first press as a separate state to a repeated hold. IsDown is a function not an array btw, but that should't make a difference here.

Answer (score 0):

You are always setting `IsFirstPress` if the key is down, which might not be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve with `IsFirstPress`, as the keystate cannot remember any previous presses anyways. If you want to mark with this bit, that it's the first time you recognized the key being down, then your logic is wrong in the corresponding `if` statement.

`keystates[i] & WasHeldDown` evaluates to true if you already set the bit `WasHeldDown` earlier for this keystate.
In that case, what you may want to do is actually remove the `IsFirstPress` bit by xor-ing it: `keystates[i] ^= IsFirstPress`

Comment: your right, I was wrong with my trying to turn of IsFirstPress. I did have the code just turning it on, but I wanted to make it just turned of, not toggled. Corrected my question.